# Split translations into several files but only 1 domain

Tags: symfony

I'm setting up a translation process in my app and I would like to organize my translations labels into several files but only 1 domain. 
I strongly would like to keep using twig through {%trans%}{%endtrans%} or | trans without needing to specify the domain each time.

I tried to define an yml import in my messages.fr.yml file :

```
imports:
- { resource: secondFile.fr.yml }
```

But id doesn't seem to work : the labels in the second file are not taken in account.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: How many files do you want to have for one domain?

Comment: not sure maybe ~5-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add as many files as you can just by setting last parameter to the `addResource` method on a `translator` service:

```
$translator->addResource('yml', 'secondFile.fr.yml', 'fr_FR', 'messages');
```

Comment: hi, Im trying to achieve the same but don't know where should I place this extra resource loadind, any help?